# Как создать текст внизу терминала и редактировать его отдельной функцией? Python

Tags: python

Как сделать так, чтобы внизу консоли можно было добавить свой текст и редактировать его функцией наподобее `dtext.edit("Hello!", down)`. [image: Как должно получиться]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для консолей совместимых с ECMA-48 (большинство Линукс консолей) управление ведется через ESC-последовательность.

Напиши свою функцию принт, которая будет обновлять прогресс-бар

```
ESC = b'\x1B' # Начинает ESC-последовательность
LF = b'\x0A' # \n Перевод на следующую строку
CR = b'\x0D' # \r Перевод в начало строки
CSI = b'[' # Ввод управляющей последовательности
EL = b'K' # Очистить строку. 2 - всю строку

import time
import sys
import shutil

screen_size = shutil.get_terminal_size()
sys.stdout.buffer.write(LF*screen_size.lines)
# прокрутить экран в конец


i = 0 # счётчик

def nprint(text):
    global i
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(ESC+CSI+b'2'+EL+CR) 
    # стирает строчку и переходит в начало
    print(text) 
    # на свободной строчке пишем текст и переходим на новую
    print('progress: '+ '|'*i + ' '*(10-i) , i*10, '%', end='') 
    # а потом обновляем прогресс-бар
    # end='' - значит остаемся в строке
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # для отрисовки недопечатанной строки
    i+=1
   
for text in ['один','два','три','ЧЕТЫРЕ','пять','шесть']:
    nprint(text)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Перевод документации https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=console_codes&category=4

Кроссплатформенное управление терминалом я рекомендую делать через https://github.com/tartley/colorama Там есть управление кареткой и цветом.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то. Дело в том, что мне нужно прикрепить этот статусбар на нижнюю границу, как, например, здесь ( ```https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BsUV.png``` ). А этот код пишет статусбар на строке после ввода ( ```https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqs0f.png``` )

Comment: @ДенисОрлов прокрутить экран в конец не сложно. добавил в код